# Process crashed in a thread that shouldn't be running

Tags: c, multithreading, gdb

I have a multi-threaded process that crashed due to a SEGV, and GDB shows this strange looking backtrace:

```
Thread 1 (LWP 3726):
#0  0x00000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x00000000 in ?? ()
```

This is a thread that has already exited but hasn't been joined. Can I believe this backtrace? Has this thread really been scheduled even though it has finished? All other threads appear to be in a sensible state. This is on an ARM embedded system running Linux kernel 3.10.

Comment: Looks like you scribbled on the stack pointer and are now executing at address 0x0 which generally causes SEGV.

Comment: are you sure this is not just the fact that the signal handler is call in this thread context

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint, perhaps your binary is compiled with no debug information (option -g for GCC). Perhaps the backtrace would look more informatively using this option and you get more ideas. Or the backtrace looks so because of a corrupted stack...